# Exit X back to command line

Tags: x11, xorg, freebsd

I have a problem exiting X to get back to the command line. After starting X, <kbd>⎇ alt</kbd>-<kbd>⎈ ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F*N*</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*N*</kbd> seem to stop functioning.

I tried to use <kbd>⎇ alt</kbd>-<kbd>⎈ ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>⌫ bksp</kbd> to kill X after enabling zap. However, I only get back a blank screen (the same thing happening when I try to switch to another virtual console).

I *can* `ssh` into the computer; and the computer is working normally except for the display.

Comment: Maybe desktop grabs alt-ctrl-fnX ? (alt-fnX works once in terminal). Anything interesting in Xorg.*.log ?

Comment: @yth Could you update your question to include the version of FreeBSD you are using, and the type of your graphics card? This is known to be a bit fragile in FreeBSD, but there are workarounds.

Comment: I am using FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p2 and I am using Intel builtin graphics (3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller).

Comment: The log file looks normal, except maybe for the last few lines. Please see below.
[   128.672] (WW) config/devd: devd socket is lost
[   128.673] (EE) config/devd: fail to connect to devd
[   128.755] (II) config/devd: terminating backend...
[   128.755] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[   128.755] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[   128.755] (II) UnloadModule: "kbd"
[   128.840] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Answer (score 2):

There are known issues with switching between X and vty consoles in FreeBSD. See, for example, [this bug report](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201461) on the FreeBSD bugzilla. Although it relates specifically to the use of an nVidia card, some of the advice in the comments is worth trying here.

Make sure you're using the latest available version of the video driver for your card, and check the value of `kern.vty`:

```
$ sysctl kern.vty
```

If it returns `kern.vty: vt`, you're using the (default) `vt` driver. The driver should allow switching between X and console, but sometimes it doesn't restore the console correctly, leaving a blank screen. As a first step, you can try enabling text mode, which causes the system to remain in text mode, rather than switching to VGA mode. Add this to `/boot/loader.conf` and reboot:

```
hw.vga.textmode=1
```

If this doesn't fix the problem you are seeing, you can then try reverting the previous change, and instead enabling the older `sc` system console driver, by adding this to `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
kern.vty=sc
```

Again, reboot and test.

If this still doesn't fix your problem, it's probably worth spending some time looking over related bug reports on the FreeBSD bug tracker, or on the FreeBSD forums.